# Binary Substraction with using two's complement

Tags: math, binary

I'm kinda new to binary arithmetic and I did an exercise regarding binary substraction. I got a solution but it is...not entirely correct. (consider the two unsigned bits!)

The task is: 00101 - 11101

First step is to use two's complement on 11101 and we get: 00010 with one's complement and after that we add one and get 00011, now we can add the numbers to get: 01000.

When I convert 01000 "back" I get 24 so the number 01000 should be -24, but why isn't there a 1 in the leftmost place? The correct solution should be: 101000 (solution from the book), but what do we have to calculate to get this solution?

Is the two's complement 00011 not correct? If we add 00011 and 11101 we get 00000 so 00011 should be correct.

Comment: If both of the original numbers are positive, then you've forgotten to extend the sign bit when you took the two's complement. Try making both values 8 bits (or even 6), and then recalculate the two's complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's an implicit bit that's being introduced in that solution.

"The correct solution should be: **1**01000 (solution from the book)"

If you were working with an architecture that restricted you to only 5 bits then it would be the case that `11101 = -3`, which would mean the answer would be `01000`.

By the sounds of things the assignment hasn't specified the number of bits that you should be working with. Your answer isn't necessarily wrong but I think you should assume that if you get a number like `11101` and are told that it is positive that there is an extra, implicit zero in front of it (or possibly more if they have explicitly told you so).

**Extra Info:**
The maximum positive number you can have under 2s compliment, is two less than the value given by the most significant bit e.g.
For a 5 bit system, `max_positive = 01110 = 14`.

This hypothetical 5bit architecture would probably convert the 2s compliment number back into a positive one and then add it (because subtracting a negative number is same as adding the positive of that number).
e.g.

```
  00101 - 11101
= 00101 + (~(11101 - 1))
= 00101 + (~11100)
= 00101 + (00011)
= 01000
```

Sources / Helpful Tools:

- http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=a61f5ebd0b65d21b82d6a49bab91ecef
- https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the 2's complement of the first number i.e 00101<sub>2</sub>.

The 2's complement of 00101<sub>2</sub> is 11011<sub>2</sub>.

Now adding this to 11101<sub>2</sub>, we get 111000<sub>2</sub> which corresponds to -24<sub>10</sub> since the most significant digit is the sign bit.

NOTE: This is assuming that both the numbers are positive.

Comment: why? the bits are unsigned. We take the two's complement of the subtrahend which is 11101.

Comment: How does `111000` correspond to `-24`? The two's complement of `111000` is `001000`, right?